# gopro hd/tv out cable

Tags: hardware

I was recently given a hero hd 960 gopro camera with only usb cable.which cable do I need for these two ports I wish to setup but without a live feed mounting this is next to impossible. [image]
Which cable do I need for the hd/tv ports as seen on top right photo.

Comment: can whoever downvoted this question perhaps give a reason why?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cable you are looking for is [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I4CMTHI) on Amazon.

It is a 2.5mm TRRS jack to 3x RCA component cable.

However, this is a very old model of GoPro, and could be hard to find manufacturer's original cables.